# How to remove KDE from login options

Tags: kde, uninstall

I am a new user to Linux and Ubuntu. I was going through the Complete Linux Manual, but I realized that it's all about the Ubuntu 16.04 and I started with 18.04. Anyway, I was going through and tried the KDE-plasma desktop environment and didn't really like it. Everything was too small.

I think I have fully deleted it, but I can still see some left overs in my /etc/ file. (i.e. gd3, and kubuntu-default-settings) and it's still a log in option for my machine. I have read a bunch of answers and nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Along with criticism.
Thanks

Comment: Re. "I have read a bunch of answers and nothing seems to work.", I posted an answer which I hope isn't something you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the login option, delete the file *plasma.desktop* from within */usr/share/xsessions*.

You can do that by carefully running

```
sudo rm /usr/share/xsessions/plasma.desktop
```

from the terminal of your choice.